# Survey JS long loading times status code 302

Tags: javascript, surveyjs

I am trying to load `survey.jquery.min.js` and it is taking a long time. Is this something that I am doing wrong when calling it or is it a survey js issue?

Called before `</body>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/survey-jquery/survey.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Http header com/survey-jquery/survey.jquery.min.js**

```
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 
Remote Address: [2606:4700::6810:7aaf]:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: public, s-maxage=600, max-age=60
cf-cache-status: EXPIRED
cf-ray: 79a7e93c7ac371cf-LHR
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
date: Thu, 16 Feb 2023 17:13:18 GMT
fly-request-id: 01GSDKE0EQKG6989ZPSPDXG931-lhr
location: /survey-jquery@1.9.74/survey.jquery.min.js
server: cloudflare
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding
via: 1.1 fly.io
x-content-type-options: nosniff
:authority: unpkg.com
:method: GET
:path: /survey-jquery/survey.jquery.min.js
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="110"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: script
sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0
```

I have tried to load the page on different devices and network to rule them out as possible issues.

Comment: so don't use the CDN?

Answer (score 1):

unpkg CDN was unstable for several days. You can install our libraries from npm and let your clients download them from your website.

Thank you,
Andrew
SurveyJS Team